# How did the Enteprise and Discovery survive that long in S2 E14 of DIS?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

If we look at other fights between starships in any other *Star Trek* series we see that battles between starships usually last (if both are set on destroying each other) about two minutes at most.

Yet in *Discovery* we see that the two ships are fighting on for like 30 minutes. Also to keep in mind is that Control had like two dozen ships with hundreds of drones.

Now I get that the *Discovery* had to survive but the *Enterprise* should have been blown to pieces within the first minute of the fight.

Comment: In fact, the Enterprise is the only ship that had to survive that fight due to pre-exiting canon. https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PlotArmor /s

Comment: "about two minutes at most" Citation needed

Comment: @BrianOrtiz https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e3cYO-vlTpk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uZPzg8_jZyQ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kIMGFq8_OJM https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-cB2-k_Vf_U https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHDMHfuzMv0

Comment: @BrianOrtiz I realize that in the first one the Defiant doesn't have shields but still...